# meaning of the symbol $Z_n^*$ in discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups

I was reading discrete Mathematics, and i found a symbol $$Z_n^*.$$ I don't know what it means.
The text says that the "image" with the multiplication operator is an abelian group.
can any one explain.

Comment: What book is this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe the author is talking about the group of unit elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ ?

Comment: This is indeed a more or less established notation for that. But I haven't used it after encountering $\Bbb Z_n^\times$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is probably the multiplicative group modulo $n$ whose elements are those which are specifically coprime to $n$.

In order for a subset of residues modulo $n$ to form a group under multiplication, one of the first things to note is that none of its elements can be a zero divisor.

Here is a link to a page describing this:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Multiplicative_Group_of_Reduced_Residues

I may well be wrong. There are a number of notations that can be encountered for this, but and there is no hard-and-fast standard.

Answer (score -1):

it means modulo n i.e after doing binary operation on a,b dividing the ans by n, then remainder is d final ans